# Passing correct context with "this" to external method from class

Tags: javascript, typescript, class, this

Let's say I have a very simple class that extends other classes, and an object of functions i'm passing to class B

```
const actions = {
   doSomething: (this: B, foo: boolean) => {
      console.log('from do something', this.text, foo);
   }
}
class B {
  actions = actions;
  text: string;
  constructor() {
    this.text = 'abc';
  }
}
class A extends B {
   runAction(foo) {
      this.actions.doSomething(false);
   }
}


const instance = new A();
instance.runAction(); // 'from do something, undefined, false'
```

ts compiler is also saying the `this` context isn't correct when calling from within `runAction`

Is there a better way to do this?

We have over 500 actions, and we want to provide access to the class data to every action and don't want to pass the arguments through all the actions.

Comment: sorry @CertainPerformance, the ts compiler itself, i've just edited my question

Comment: "*we don't want to pass the arguments through all the actions.*" - what do you mean by that, `actions.doSomething(this, false)`? It's not any longer than what you currently have :-)

Comment: Btw no point in doing `actions = actions`, unless you later want to change which of multiple `actions` objects a `B` instance should use. Just refer to the static constant directly.

Comment: Why don't you simply define the actions as methods on the instance?

Comment: because there's 500odd actions @Bergi, with a huge range of data available on the class and each action is different in terms of what it can use, and i'd have to define a class for every category of actions, rather than a file just exporting an object of easily testable functions

Comment: There's multiple classes that extend the root class, not in this simple example, importing the static reference would mean i'd have to import in every file extending the root class @Bergi

Comment: "*I'd have to define a class for every category of actions*" - isn't that what you're doing anyway with `A` and other subclasses? "*i'd have to import [the static reference] in every file extending the root class*" - not worse than having to import the root class in all of these modules :-) But you could kill two birds with one stone by using `static actions = actions` in `B`, then refer to `B.actions` everywhere instead of `this.actions`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This

```
this.actions.doSomething(false);
```

calls the method with a `this` of `this.actions`. But `this.actions` is the plain object with the `doSomething` method - *not* the instance itself. You will need to use `.call` instead, as well as changing the `doSomething` arrow function to a regular function/method so it can capture a different `this`. The `foo` argument should be typed too (or removed).

Typing `this` inside `runAction` could be useful as well, though not always necessary.

```
const actions = {
   doSomething(this: B, foo: boolean) {
      console.log('from do something', this.text, foo);
   }
}
class A extends B {
   runAction(this: A) {
      this.actions.doSomething.call(this, false);
   }
}
```

Comment: Thankyou, so simple i should have known this...